# Exporting html table data to excel

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm trying to export html table data to excel. using the below code I'm able to export to excel

```
 $scope.Export = function () {
    var blob = new Blob([document.getElementById('exportable').innerHTML], {
        type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=utf-8"
    });
    saveAs(blob, "Report.xls");
```

};

But when I add pagination to table, I'm not able to export all data from all pages instead it is possible to export data from only 1st page.

Please help me.. Thanks in advance

Comment: Probably you should manually construct whole html, iterating over all pages, some like `for(var i = 1; i <= pages; i++) html += getHtmlForPage(i);` and send it, instead of only visible part -
 `document.getElementById('exportable').innerHTML`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to angularjs. I didn't understood.. Can you explain me what is happening here?

Comment: What I said is not about angular at all. At your case you should fetch all pages, not only current one, and send them to server.